# Converting mydict.keys into an array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift2

I have a dictionary of type `[String:String]` and want to ask all keys into an array of Strings.

```
ortdict = [
    "aaa": "eins",
    "bbb": "zwei",
    "ccc": "drei"
]
let mykeys = ortdict.keys
print("\nkeys:", mykeys)
```

The printout then is:

`keys: LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, String>, String>(_base: ["aaa": "eins", "bbb": "zwei", "ccc": "drei"], _transform: (Function))`

That's not what I want, but I can not find a method that produces an array of my keys. Do I have to program this method myself (as swift-replacement for the previous allkeys-method for a `NSDictionary`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
let keysArray = ortdict.keys.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array` initializer to transform the `LazyMapCollection` into an array:

```
let mykeys = Array(ortdict.keys)

print("\nkeys:", mykeys)
```

Prints:

> keys: ["bbb", "aaa", "ccc"]

Note that a Swift Dictionary is an unordered collection. If you want the keys ordered, sort the resulting array instead of sorting the dictionary itself:

```
let mykeys = Array(ortdict.keys).sort()
```

Result:

> keys: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]